# How to manage user privileges? (Php, Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

As with my previous posts, I am creating an online storefront. What I am trying to do this time (which is the final part I need to complete) is to allow the Admin OR the user who posted the item to be able to edit/delete the item.
This is the code that I created to check if the 'seller id' of that specific item is the same as $_SESSION['user_id']. If it is, enable that user (if he/she is not the admin) to edit/delete that item. But the problem is, only the Admin is able to edit/delete the item even with that code. Anyone know why?

```
<?php
      $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "php24sql", "some password", "smithside");
      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM lots";
      $results2 = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $query2);
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2); 
      $seller = $row2['seller'];
      }
      ?>
      <?php if ($accessLevel == 'Admin' || $seller == $_SESSION['user_id']) { ?>
      <a class="button edit" 
        href="index.php?content=lotdelete&cat_id=<?php echo $cat_id_in; ?>&lot_id=<?php echo $lot->getLot_id(); ?>">Delete
      </a>
      <a class="button edit" 
        href="index.php?content=lotedit&cat_id=<?php echo $cat_id_in; ?>&lot_id=<?php echo $lot->getLot_id(); ?>">Edit
      </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help if you can! Thanks!

Comment: @DagurTidalwave Please change the database credentials. They might not matter to you (they could be temporary credentials to a private development server), but it is good practice to always remove private information, including passwords, before posting.

Comment: You really should change that password on your database, right away. It's been out there on multiple questions you've asked.

Comment: It's too late, you may have edited it, but it is viewable in the edit history. Change it on your database server ASAP!

Comment: @DagurTidalwave Have you [started your session[(http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)? You need to call `session_start()` on every page that can load values from the `SESSION` array.

Comment: @T0xicCode yes, I've done that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['user_id']`?

Comment: It may be one of the values stored in the 'contact' table of my database. For example, my name is Matt, and I have 3 as my user_id. When Matt logs in, $_SESSION['user_id'] will become 3.

Comment: "it may be .." is an assumption, which must not be true. Please var_dump `$_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to determine the value of both `$seller` and `$_SESSION['user_id']`. You need to be certain of the value they have.

Comment: @T0xicCode I used var_dump on both $seller and $_SESSION['user_id'] and this appeared:
string(1) "0" string(1) "7"

Comment: That means that either the seller is not being saved to the database, or the session user_id is not being updated correctly. I'd start with the code to save a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1.) you have an closing`}` with no opening `{` :

```
...
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2); 
  $seller = $row2['seller'];
  // } <<<<==== ????
  ?>
  ....
```

2.) you may start the session first:

```
session_start();
...
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2); 
  $seller = $row2['seller'];
  // } <<<<==== ????
  ?>
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem with your code. You are selecting * from the 'lots' table without a specific constraint within a WHERE statement. When the query is ran you are only selecting the top row of whatever was returned from the 'lots' table. When the comparison is done between $seller and $_SESSION['user_id'] the $seller variable is ambiguous. Here is some updated code that may help.

Also...try to avoid using * in SQL statements. By selecting columns that you will be reading will reduce the amount of data that needs to be parsed. Plus, it's good practice.

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM lots WHERE <columnName> = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
  $results2 = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $query2);
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2); 
  $seller = $row2['seller'];
  }
  ?>
  <?php if ($accessLevel == 'Admin' || $seller == $_SESSION['user_id']) { ?>
```